Why can't I declare this array of double pointers in C++
void foo(){
        static const int tree1[][2] = {
            {FULL,1}, 
            {FULL,2},
            {EMPTY,4},
            {EMPTY,5},
            {EMPTY,3}
        };
        static const int tree2[][2] = {
            {FULL,1},
            {EMPTY,2},
            {FULL,3},
            {LEFT,4},
            {LEFT,5},
            {EMPTY,6},
            {RIGHT,7},
            {RIGHT,8},
            {EMPTY,9}
        };
        static const int ** whydoesthisnotwork[]= {tree1,tree2};
}

I first tried to declare this as a single structure, which obviously didn't work, so then I tried to declare this with many variations of that code but I always ran into issues like
cannot convert ‘const int (*)[2]’ to ‘const int**’ in initialization

Shouldn't const int(*)[2] and const int**be the same thing?
const int* const* doesn't work either

Because an array of arrays is not the same as a pointer to a pointer... See e.g. this old answer of mine for an illustration of the differences.

As for the array to pointer decay, it only happen for the outer array. E.g. tree1 will decay to &tree1[0], which is a pointer to an array of two const int elements. Or const int (*)[2].

The only scenario where type** has anything to do with arrays is when it points to the first element in an array of pointers. And only then. You have no array of pointers here so you shouldn't be using that type.

Thanks for the comments,my assumption was that arrays internally were no more than a special const * type that happened to point to a larger area of memory, clearly I was wrong.
(A scuffed "solution" that actually works)
void foo(){
        static const int * tree1[] = {
            new int[2]{FULL,1}, 
            new int[2]{FULL,2},
            new int[2]{EMPTY,4},
            new int[2]{EMPTY,5},
            new int[2]{EMPTY,3}
        };
        static const int * tree2[] = {
            new int[2]{FULL,1},
            new int[2]{EMPTY,2},
            new int[2]{FULL,3},
            new int[2]{LEFT,4},
            new int[2]{LEFT,5},
            new int[2]{EMPTY,6},
            new int[2]{RIGHT,7},
            new int[2]{RIGHT,8},
            new int[2]{EMPTY,9}
        };
        static const int ** whydoesthisnotwork[]= {tree1,tree2};
}


That's a lot of memory leaks. Since you're programming in C++, why not use std::array and references instead?
